# Rails 4.2 undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to Rails and I am having trouble with the will_paginated gem on my ruby app. I have searched for answers but nothing clear has been obvious.

Here is my code.

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :plan)
    Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)    
  end
end
```

And the index

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>

....................
<tbody>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.plan %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>

  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
   </table>

 <%= will_paginate @posts %>

 <br>

 <%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

This is the error

```
undefined method `total_pages' for # ActiveRecord
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks very much" If I need to provide more code I will.

Comment: Have you restarted your app after gem installation?

Comment: Hi. Yes. No change. Same error.

Comment: Why do you paginate your model within `post_params`? Could you please show the index action as well?

Comment: Never mind - you're using `inherited_resources` gem, aren't you?

Comment: Hi. Yes. I have the gem installed. It makes no difference.

Comment: In the gem troubleshooting section it says of this error: Not using Sphinx or Ferret but still getting this error? Make sure you’re passing a **paginated** collection to the will_paginate helper, not an ordinary array. ??

Comment: Do you really think inherited_resources is a good idea for your first project? It does a crazy amount of magic, you might be better off learning how to do things the standard rails way first.